# Why can't we generate the project.pbxproj file in an xcode project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

There are often conflicts in the project.pbxproj file when merging between developers in a shared xcode project. Why is it that there is no clear way to generate the project.pbxproj from the project directory file hierarchy rather than managing and editing that file directly. Or more to the point, why does xcode have it's own file structure using "groups" rather than relying on the project directory on disk?

Comment: Merging storyboards can be even more fun right?

Comment: Xcode works on virtual management of folders so that its easy to access any resource by only name and extension without providing complete path.

You cannot generate the project file by replicating the physical folder because there is multiple app target support available.  for example i have ten folders containing 10 files each. in one of my target i only need 5 folder and in the other target i need all 10. this target management is done using project file. How ever if you have only one app target then you can copy and save the project file for future reference and corrections.